# When I use SSH with web browser on AWS Console. How I can set my security group source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ssl, amazon-ec2

Recently new SSH access method comes up on AWS Console.
Just I select my instance and click connect button and SSH web console shows up!
But if I wanna using that I have to set security group source from all.
When I set that just from my IP. SSH web console doesn't work.
I don't want to set that from all.
How can I set that just from aws network or my ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean **SSH connection** (not SSL; I edited your question to change that) through [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html). This would explain why it does not work when you use your IP.

To limit SSH traffic when using `EC2 Instance Connect` you have to use [AWS API ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html) for the service:

> (Browser-based client) We recommend that your instance allows inbound SSH traffic from the recommended **IP block published for the service**. Use the EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT filter for the service parameter to get the **IP address ranges** in the EC2 Instance Connect subset.

Thus, you have to allow IP ranges used by the service, not your home/work address.

Comment: Correct. EC2 Instance Connect establishes an HTTPS connection to AWS, and then AWS establishes an SSH connection to the instance. This is why the IP ranges need to reference the `EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT` range rather than home/work. Another option is to use the Systems Manager Session Manager

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for clarification. I removed the home/work range.

Comment: Thank you guys I found ip list from aws on this page https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
In that file, I choose IP range for my ec2 region and I set that up in security group source list.

Comment: This approach allows any EC2 instance in any account to brute force into the EC2 instance. There should be a better approach.